# unable to step into my local service that is in my solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I know this has been asked before but I just cannot figure this out. I believe I have covered everything that has been brought up already but I'll cover those.

I am getting this message when I try to step into a service that is a project that is currently in my solution:

[image]

I have 3 projects in my solution:

SuburbanCustPortal  <-- my website
SuburbanHub   <-- my serice
WebsiteLogging   <-- my logging project (no significance here)

I read that I should check the following items:

1. Make sure that debug is on. I have this in both of my project's web.config:
2. Make sure they are both using the same .net version. They are both on the .net framework 4.0.
3. Make sure Enable Just Your Code is unchecked:

[image]

The service is pointed to a local url:

[image]

I can pull up the service in my browser without error:

[image]

This is my settings for iis:

[image]

I have restarted visual studio, the computer and removed the service and added it back.

I cannot, for the life of me, figure this out. If I have missed anything I am willing to give it a shot.

It is very important that I get this resolved so I can get this project out this weekend so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**IN RESPONSE TO Sanket Shah**

I do not have the option w3wp.exe:

[image]

**SOMETHING I FORGOT TO MENTION**

I have set debug=true in both of my projects:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Also, I wanted to add that I have been able to step into my service before but since coming back to the project recently, I am not able too. I have a break point on the line that calls the service and when I try to F11 in to it, I get the above message.

**IN RESPONSE TO Pawel**

I have tried setting symbols the follow ways and neither allowed me to step in:

[image][image]

I have even tried to use the Microsoft symbols:

[image]

**IN RESPONSE TO Pawel #2**

[image]

**ADDITION INFO**

I just noticed this, I'm not sure if it is related:

[image]

**ADDITIONAL INFO ABOUT DEBUG MODE**

I have all projects set in debug mode:

[image]

Comment: Could you please update your service reference , and Uncheck Resuse Type in the dialog box

Comment: Try to "Attach Debugger to Process" option and select w3wp.exe

Comment: @Sajeetharan Where do I find this option? I do not get prompted with a dialog box when it updates.

Comment: The image you have already posted is the dialog box i mentioned, when you right click and configure your service

Comment: @SanketShah I have updated my question. I do not have w3wp.exe in the process list.

Comment: @Sajeetharan I unchecked the option then I updated the service. I reran the project and I got the same message.

Comment: @SanketShah I did check the option to Show processes from all users and it wasn't listed.

Comment: Right-click the solution, select Properties.
Under "Startup Project" switch from "Single startup project" to "Multiple startup projects".
Set Action to "Start" for the WCF project.

Comment: @Sajeetharan That's how I do it anyhow. It starts up the WCF Test Client when I do. Would you like a printscreen of that window?

Comment: In sync with @ErocM. WCF Test Client should help.

Comment: @SanketShah it's grayed out, I cannot select it.

Comment: Are symbols loaded? You can verify this in the 'Modules' window (Debug -> Windows -> Modules)

Comment: @Pawel I have with no luck. I have updated my question with print screens. Do you see anything wrong with the way I did it?

Comment: @ErocM this is not the window I was referring to. You showed the symbol settings and not modules window

Comment: @Pawel I believe so. I've not used this option before. I have posted a printscreen of what it shows.

Comment: May sound silly, but have you rebuilt the whole solution in debug mode instead of release? Try to clean the solution and rebuild the whole thing.

Comment: Another tip: One way is to right click in the service project, select `Debug` in the menu and then `Start new instance`. I usually do that when I need to debug more than 1 project in the same solution.

Comment: Just to clarify: Someone mentioned the option to attach to `w3wp.exe`. This would be possible if you actually had the project running on IIS (the main one, installed on Windows) and not the Express that runs via Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you try adding `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` in the service code?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I have but just since I am willing to try anything I have just cleaned the solution and tried debugging. I then cleaned the solution and restarted, I then cleaned the solution, restarted, changed the ports of both projects, removed the service from my web appliction and added it back with the new ports... no luck :(

Comment: @ashes999 I'm not sure I understand what it will accomplish. Can you clarify?

Comment: Have you tried the option of starting a new instance via the debug option (I've posted a comment about it).

Comment: @MelanciaUK When I do this, it starts only the project that I right click on so I guess I don't understand what it is you want me to do. Sorry...

Comment: You said that you cleaned the solution and tried debugging, cleaned again and restarted, etc. But have you actually checked if the output mode is set to `Debug` and not `Release`? Just to double check.

Comment: You set one of the projects as your startup. Bang it on. When it's already running, go to the other project and follow those instructions. You will then have 2 projects to be debugged. One started automatically and the other one manually by yourself.

Comment: @MelanciaUK I rechecked it and posted a print screen in case I overlooked something.

Comment: @MelanciaUK My web project will error out if my service is not running so I have to start both of them at the time I start the debugging.

Comment: But this doesn't make much sense. One should depend on the other, not both depending on both, right? Set your WCF as the startup, and start the Website manually right after.

Comment: @ErocM add that to your local service code -- somewhere after the service starts up -- and Visual Studio should prompt you to attach to your current Visual Studio and start debugging.

Comment: I can see you have some errors showing up somewhere. Also, when I say set the output to Debug, I mean that dropdown in the Visual Studio menu bar (close to the button that runs the project in a browser of your choice).

Comment: I went through the MSDN documentation and you already tried the 2 solutions proposed. First, you could just set your solution properties to start multiple projects. The second one is that of using the Debug menu (solution explorer) and start a new instance. This last one is useful if one project needs to have another one already running to be able to start properly (can't work if all of them start together).

Comment: So, I think your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Your solution/project/settings file(s) might be corrupted. If you create a new solution from scratch, adding two new projects which mimic your current structure, can you debug them ? If that works, gradually move the code over while keeping checking that debug keeps working.

Comment: @ashes999 I added that line to the part of my service class where I want to debug and it lets me debug from that point... I have no idea why...

Comment: @Alex I believe you might be right, let me try that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61289/discussion-on-question-by-erocm-unable-to-step-into-my-local-service-that-is-in).

Comment: @bluefeet I tried to do that and it gave me an error at the time.

Comment: @ErocM No problem, I've moved the comments into chat. Feel free to continue the discussion there.

Comment: Regarding "I do not have the option w3wp.exe" -> You might need to check the box "Show processes from all users"

Comment: Sometimes it helps if you start off with a clean vanilla solution and verify it works there, then work from there up towards your "real" solution. You end up with two solutions whereas one is working and one is not. The closer the two get, the more likely you will find the difference that makes it fail. I know this is not a very tasty thought, but I have often fallen back to this approach and it usually did the trick. You will especially need a diff tool to view the differences between csproj files, .user files, .config files, etc. (I presume you have tried a fresh checkout already).

Comment: @Alex if you post your solution to rebuild the solution file, I will give you the credit. That is what worked for me.

Comment: Done. Fun fact: I had to face a very similar issue just yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution/project/settings file(s) might be / seems like it is corrupted. If you create a new solution from scratch, adding new projects which mimic your current structure, you can try and see if debugging works properly.

If that works, gradually move the code over while keeping checking that debug keeps working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this doesn't work.

I have a work-around for you, which you verified in the comments: add `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` somewhere in your service after it starts. This should pop up some sort of exception window, with a list of Visual Studio instances open. Pick the one with your solution and click OK, and it should attach correctly to that location.

Annoying? Yes. In my experience with Visual Studio, it can be very finicky sometimes about debugging into Windows services. This is the only reliable way to do it that I know about.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers, you can do two things:

1. **Close your solution**, delete [solution-name].suo file, reopen solution. See if your problem still persists.
2. Open a command prompt as admin, cd %windir%\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319, execute this `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`.

Answer (score 0):

In solution, have you tried to set all assemblies (client and server) to start in debug mode rather than trying to attach it after launch ? (right click on solution in the top of Solution explorer, startup, multiple startup project, choose "start" for every assembly which is an entry point : server, client, etc).

Have you tried to run only the "server" part in debug mode (the one which is not debuggable) and call it for example with soap ui ?
You should try to see if you can run it directly and debug it without the "step in" from another process, or if it also fails to load in debugger even if started directly.

FYI, if you use IIS Express it's normal you don't see "w3wp.exe", which is for IIS. You may have a iisexpress.exe process, or in some cases aspnet_wp.exe.
Don't forget to check "show processes for all users" in Debug->Attach to process window if you choose to hook on existing process rather than doing that I was saying first.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties of the solution select Multi statup project and select all projects with start, then debug the solution.